# How do you escape foo=bar in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a case where I need to pass an argument that has an equal sign in it:

```
- name: install virtualenv                                                          
        pip:                                                                              
            state: present                                                                
            name: mypackage                                                          
            virtualenv_python: /usr/bin/python3.6                                         
            virtualenv: "{{ perfdash_tools_venv_path }}"                                  
            extra_args: "--extra-index-url=https://myrepo"
```

Ansible thinks I'm trying to do k=v style:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: template, trigger

The error appears to be in 'tasks/main.yml': line 10, column 43, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

            extra_args: "--extra-index-url=https://myrepo"
                                          ^ here

There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.
```

`!unsafe` doesn't seem to apply in this case.

(Yes, for now I can use whitespace, but that isn't always possible.)

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Try to adopt example a bit (throwing away `perfdash_tools_venv_path`, and converting to the full-fledged play).

Answer (score 2):

You can escape characters using `{{ }}` around it.

In your case `{{'='}}` will escape the equal sign.

Here is how your playbook should look like:

```yaml
- name: install virtualenv                                                          
  pip:                                                                              
    state: present
    name: mypackage
    virtualenv_python: /usr/bin/python3.6
    virtualenv: "{{ perfdash_tools_venv_path }}"
    extra_args: "--extra-index-url{{'='}}https://myrepo"
```